# show images with the right property

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

In my gallery I want to show my images, but I have two formats of images: 1/1:square format, 2/3:portrait format.

I created a class (result) for my `ul` container and I add the images to it. By modifying some properties I center it vertically and horizontally. Some images appear smaller because of their format I can't just let width (8em).

**My question is:** Can I add `frm` as an attribute to my image tag like `src`? If yes , I'll have this value from my database.

My script doesn't work. My Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("ul.result li img").attr('frm')='1/1') 
    {
        $("ul.result li img").css('width','10em');
    }

    if ($("ul.result li img").attr('frm')='2/3') 
    {
        $("ul.result li img").css('width','8em');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not add two empty dummy css classes (`square` and `portrait`) and use the appropriate ones when loading the images in the first place? (eg. where you'd currently set your frm attribute). Wouldn't even need to be empty css classes, you could actually just attach your width attributes to them and be done with everything.

Comment: If you want to add a home made attribute, use  a HTML5 data attribute, so it is valid : `data-portrai`t and `data-landscape` will do fine. those attributes can be access via CSS or js

Comment: `if (foo = 'bar')` will **always** be true (`set foo to 'bar'. Did you do that? Then return true`). Use `==` and `===` for conditional checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can use the `data` method (http://api.jquery.com/data/) and properties on the elements in your html to store whatever it is you want. For your reference, that looks like:

**HTML**

```
<img src="file" data-format="square" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("img").each(function () {
       if ($(this).data("format") == "square") {
          // process square image element ("this")
       } else {
          // process normal image
       }
    });
});
```

Now, that said - as others have noted you might consider using css classes to change your style rather than writing a bunch of Javascript code. The only reason I would consider writing the javascript (as opposed to css) is if there are complicated calculations that need to happen. Most of the time, though, if you structure your html correctly you can do whatever you need with pure css (no Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using javascript for this?

You have a database property, and you're changing a css property based on a database property. That's what classes are for!

```
<img class=<?php (img.frm=="1/1"?"square":"portrait") ?> src=..... />
```

Then, in your css:

```
.square{
    width: 10em;
}

.portrait{
    width: 8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to add a home made attribute, use  a HTML5 data attribute,
>   so it is valid : `data-portrait` and `data-landscape` will do fine.

those attributes can be access via CSS or js

To answer your question:

**YES you can**, but i advise to use :`data-frm` as attribute name and avoid the use of special caracter in values.

Some reading from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) :)